TreeMap, private void deleteEntry(Entry<K,V> p) случай с заметой
сперва посмотрите на этот кусок кода
            // Fix replacement
            if (p.color == BLACK)
                fixAfterDeletion(replacement);

ниже полный код метода
    /**
     * Delete node p, and then rebalance the tree.
     */
    private void deleteEntry(Entry<K,V> p) {
        modCount++;
        size--;

        // If strictly internal, copy successor's element to p and then make p
        // point to successor.
        if (p.left != null && p.right != null) {
            Entry<K,V> s = successor(p);
            p.key = s.key;
            p.value = s.value;
            p = s;
        } // p has 2 children

        // Start fixup at replacement node, if it exists.
        Entry<K,V> replacement = (p.left != null ? p.left : p.right);

        if (replacement != null) {
            // Link replacement to parent
            replacement.parent = p.parent;
            if (p.parent == null)
                root = replacement;
            else if (p == p.parent.left)
                p.parent.left  = replacement;
            else
                p.parent.right = replacement;

            // Null out links so they are OK to use by fixAfterDeletion.
            p.left = p.right = p.parent = null;

            // Fix replacement
            if (p.color == BLACK)
                fixAfterDeletion(replacement);
        } else if (p.parent == null) { // return if we are the only node.
            root = null;
        } else { //  No children. Use self as phantom replacement and unlink.
            if (p.color == BLACK)
                fixAfterDeletion(p);

            if (p.parent != null) {
                if (p == p.parent.left)
                    p.parent.left = null;
                else if (p == p.parent.right)
                    p.parent.right = null;
                p.parent = null;
            }
        }
    }

вопрос: зачем нам делать проверку так, как показано в первом блоке кода, если перед этим мы делаем проверку:
    if (replacement != null) {

и, следовательно, если замена != null, то единственный возможный случай - это то, что «p» точно черный с одной красной заменой.
и потом мы просто меняем цвет замены на черный в методе:
fixAfterDeletion(replacement);

я могу понять почему мы делаем это в отдельном методе, имею ввиду
fixAfterDeletion(replacement);

допустим что бы сгруппировать код в одном месте, в итоге будет вызнана одна строчка кода

setColor(x, BLACK);

но все же не могу понять случай с заменой, и проверкой, зачем она нужна?

Уважаемые, если вы хотите поставить минус вопросу, прошу перед этим хотя бы написать коментарий почему

Если replacement у вас будет null, то как вы сделаете операцию replacement.parent = p.parent?

@SwaD если он null мы просто не делаем этого вообще, а просто удаляем красную ноду без fixAfterDeletion, как показано в блоке else или если она черная то делаем fixAfterDeletion

В вашем коде p это передаваемое значение и внутри метода нет явного переопределения значения p.color, поэтому, на сколько можно судить, код написан "универсально" и все эти проверки не противоречат друг другу. Возможно, где то в других местах кода, которые видите и нам не показываете, все иначе и если replacement не null, то p.color обязательно BLACK то тогда эта проверка может быть избыточной. Что делает fixAfterDeletion и setColor вообще не ясно(да и похоже к вопросу не относится)

@SwaD эта проверка совсем не мешает коду работать правильно, но вопрос в другом, я просто хочу понять зачем она нужна, потому как она противоречит, тому что у красной ноды могуть быть только два наследника или ноль, в итоге мы попадем в блок с поиском наследника, у черной может бить один или два или ноль, и поэтому этот случай только для черной с одной красной заметой, и вопрос тогда, зачем проверка цвета, потому как если есть замена тогда же очевидно что проверка на цвет не нужна

Еще раз. Никто кроме вас и, возможно, вашего бизнес-эксперта с заказчиком, не скажет, зачем нужна эта проверка и зачем ее поставили(это явно были не вы). Какие у вас там ноды и каких цветов мне не известно(гадальный шар сегодня сломан, по названию метода не могу угадать, какой смысл вкладывался в код). Я вижу для вас 2 варианта: 1 - оставить как есть(работает, не трогай), 2 - убрать проверку и всесторонне протестировать

@SwaD это класическое красно-черное дерево, и код написан в официальной библиотеке, я просто питаюсь разобраться чисто для себя, потому как изучал алгоритм работы красно-черных, и порылся в коде на джаве колекциях, вижу что нету логики в том что вижу, вот и задал вопрос, может кто то знает

@SwaD это исходники java.util.TreeMap :)

Я получил ответ на англоязычном сообществе как оказалось проверка совсем не нужна, и скорее всего она несет в себе характер оповещения о том что мы удаляем черную ноду и будем делать ребалансировку дерева, кому интересно вот сылка на вопрос с ответом на английском - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78253926/treemap-private-void-deleteentryentryk-v-p-replacement-case
